# Split a full name into first and last name in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with a table that contains a field with medical provider names, formatted as Last, First Credential. I need to split the first and last name up into two separate fields, as well as cut off the credential at the end.

```
SELECT ProviderName


ProviderName
----------------------
Smith, John MD
Doe, Jane FNP
Brown, Bob PA-C
```

I'm on the right track with what I've got so far...

```
SELECT
    LEFT (ProviderName, CHARINDEX(', ', ProviderName) - 1) AS ProviderLName,
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ProviderName, CHARINDEX(', ', ProviderName), LEN(ProviderName)), ', ', '') AS ProviderFName


ProviderLName    ProviderFName
----------------------------------
Smith            John MD
Doe              Jane FNP
Brown            Bob PA-C
```

...but I'm not sure what to add to the code in order to eliminate everything after the second space (aka eliminate the credentials). What's my next step?

Comment: You can just keep doing what you're doing. Add on a search for the space character and use `left()`. You could repeat the entire subexpression for fname or chain them together inside a cte or cross apply.

Comment: @shawnt00 I guess I'm not sure what order everything needs to go in. All the methods I've tried for identifying that second space keep identifying the first one (after the comma) instead.

Comment: You might opt for another approach but I just wanted to help you down the road you started on. Here's what I had in mind: https://rextester.com/UBMK11936

Comment: @shawnt00 ah, thanks so much! That did the trick.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: @DaleK Got it, done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and answer my own question (huge thanks to [@shawnt00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322268/shawnt00) for your help getting me started!).

To reiterate, if I select `ProviderName` from my table, I end up with results like the following. This table also has a generic provider option for when a patient comes in for a basic nurse visit that turns out kind of awkward in the last-name-comma-first-name format.

```
SELECT ProviderName

ProviderName
----------------------
Smith, John MD
Doe, Jane FNP
Brown, Bob PA-C
MA-Nurse Visit, Clinical
```

In order to account for the difference in formatting for that nurse visit provider, I ended up using a `CASE` statement in my query.

```
SELECT
    (CASE 
        WHEN ProviderName LIKE '%MA-%' THEN 
            REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ProviderName), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(ProviderName)) - 1))
        ELSE 
            LEFT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ProviderName, CHARINDEX(', ', ProviderName), 
            LEN(ProviderName)), ', ', ''),
            CHARINDEX(' ',REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ProviderName, CHARINDEX(', ', ProviderName), 
            LEN(ProviderName)), ', ', '')) - 1) 
    END) AS [Provider First Name],
    (CASE
        WHEN ProviderName LIKE '%MA-%' THEN 
            SUBSTRING(ProviderName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', ProviderName) - 1)
        ELSE 
            LEFT(ProviderName, CHARINDEX(', ', ProviderName) - 1) 
    END) AS [Provider Last Name]
```

Which gives us...

```
Provider First Name     Provider Last Name
-------------------------------------------
John                    Smith
Jane                    Doe
Bob                     Brown
Clinical                MA-Nurse
```

The "visit" part of the nurse provider gets cut off, but for the purposes of the data I'm pulling, that's perfectly fine, and it doesn't make the provider name any harder to understand.

Hope this information is helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you *always* want to remove everything after the last space:

- Reverse the string
- Find the last space
- Substring it
- Reverse again.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (ProviderName VARCHAR(128));

INSERT INTO @Test (ProviderName)
VALUES
('Smith, John MD'),
('Doe, Jane FNP'),
('Brown, Bob PA-C');

SELECT ProviderName, ProviderFName, ProviderLName
    , REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ProviderFName), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(ProviderFName))+1, LEN(ProviderFName))) ProviderFnameFinal
FROM (
    SELECT
        ProviderName 
        , LEFT (ProviderName, CHARINDEX(', ', ProviderName) - 1) AS ProviderLName
        , REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ProviderName, CHARINDEX(', ', ProviderName), LEN(ProviderName)), ', ', '') AS ProviderFName
    from @Test
) X;
```

Returns

```
ProviderName    ProviderFName   ProviderLName   ProviderFnameFinal
Smith, John MD  John MD         Smith           John
Doe, Jane FNP   Jane FNP        Doe             Jane
Brown, Bob PA-C Bob PA-C        Brown           Bob
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `string_split()` and some string logic:

```
select pn.*, s.*
from ProviderName pn cross apply
     (select max(case when pn.name like ',' then replace(s.value, ',', '') end) as lastname,
             max(case when pn.name like '%, ' + s.value + '%' then s.value end) as firstname
      from string_split(pn.name, ' ') s
     ) s;
```

Note:  This assumes that there is only one comma in the string.